# Return url doesn't work with PayPal and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

My return URL is not working with `paypi-rest-sdk` and NodeJS.

Page after payment : https://space.zeo.net/g/2x2n1

And page should be : http://www.mywebsite.fr/confirm

```js
      var payment = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
          "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
          "return_url": paypalConfigs.returnUrl,
          "cancel_url": paypalConfigs.cancelUrl+request.user.id
        },
        "transactions": [{
          "amount": {
            "total": total,
            "currency": "EUR"
          },
          "description": "Commande Printwithlove"
        }]
      };

      paypal.payment.create(payment, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          if(payment.payer.payment_method === 'paypal') {
            request.session.paymentId = payment.id;
            var redirectUrl;
            for(var i=0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
              var link = payment.links[i];
              if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
                redirectUrl = link.href;
              }
            }
            response.redirect(redirectUrl);
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Did you turn on the "auto return" in your PayPal account ? You can go to this url after login to the PayPal to turn this on : https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Comment: I did... And I get the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Hey try creating the payment using developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/… i.e. just sending curl requests. If you are able to do that and redirection works, then you can eliminate this being an issue with your account settings or credentials and that the return url is properly formatted. Then try samples from github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/samples, if the samples work then the issue is likely with your app.

Eshan's suggestion could be the issue here too.

Comment: My API is using Sandbox, maybe that's the problem... How to use live ?

Answer (score 0):

Use npm paypal-rest-sdk package. I have same issues once upon a time.Then after i did a redirect the payal page. you given the **response.redirect(redirectUrl);** it's executing when read the all code asynchronous process so the redirect not working. You give the redirect code in when executing the if condition!